# How can we find $\sum\nolimits_{i = 1}^{13} {{a_i}} = ?$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $\left\{ {{a_i}} \right\}$ be an arithmetic sequence and $a_3+a_7+a_{11}=24$.

How can we find $\sum\nolimits_{i = 1}^{13} {{a_i}}  = ?$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The average of $\{a_1,...,a_{13}\}$ is going to be $a_7$, since the numbers are symmetrically spread. So the sum is $13a_7$.

Meanwhile $\{a_3,a_7,a_{11}\}$ is also an arithmetic sequence so the same thing applies. And $a_7$ must be $\frac{24}{3}=8$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Rewrite everything in terms of $a_1$ and the difference $d = a_i-a_{i-1}$.

Comment: @Arthue Please more guide.

Comment: $a_3 = a_1 + 2d, a_7 = a_1 + 6d, a_{11} = a_1 + 10d$, so $a_3+a_7+a_{11} = 3a_1 + 18d$. Do the same for $a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_{13}$, and see that you can get from one to the other without too much hassle.

Comment: You should probably address the problem in more detail.  It was not a request for a "hint", and the condition $a_3 + a_7 + a_{11} = 24$ does not allow *both* $a_1$ and $d$ to be determined.

Comment: @hardmath If they request a hint, I only give a hint. If they don't request a hint, I reserve the right to choose whether I give a full answer or a hint. And the condition $a_3 + a_7 + a_{11} = 24$ doesn't allow _either_ of $a_1$ or $d$ to be determined.

Answer (score 1):

*For sure, very basic and much less nice than alex.jordan's answer.*

Let $$a_i=A+(i-1)D\implies \sum_{i=1}^{13}a_i=13A+78 D\tag 1$$ Similarly $$a_3+a_7+a_{11}=3A+18D=24\implies A=8-6D\tag 2$$ Replace in $(1)$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{13}a_i=13A+78 D=13(8-6D)+78D=104$$